# PHP search term script but converting to multiple search fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and running [from this tutorial](http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/a-php-script-to-search-a-mysql-database/) which is a search script to search and find from db and return data. However I'm a little stuck with where I have got to.

The tutorial is based from 1 field form to search but I have my field for with 4 fields which all need to be filled and all need to match before passing a result but I am stuck with the form to PHP / class communication.

Here is what I have:

index.php

```
<?php
//Check if search data was submitted
if ( isset( $_GET['search_form'] ) ) {
  // Include the search class
  require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class.search.php' );

  // Instantiate a new instance of the search class
  $search = new search();

  // Store search term into a variable
  $search_first_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_last_name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_postcode = htmlspecialchars($_GET['postcode'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $search_reg = htmlspecialchars($_GET['reg'], ENT_QUOTES);

  // Send the search term to our search class and store the result
  $search_results = $search->search($search_first_name, $search_last_name, $search_postcode, $search_reg);
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>search customer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns center">
        <h3>search form</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php if ( $search_results ) : ?>
    <div class="results-count">
      <p><?php echo $search_results['count']; ?> results found</p>
    </div>
    <div class="results-table">
      <?php foreach ( $search_results['results'] as $search_result ) : ?>
      <div class="result">
        <p><?php echo $search_result->title; ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="search-raw">
      <pre><?php print_r($search_results); ?></pre>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-6 medium-centered large-4 large-centered columns">

        <form action="" method="get" class="search-form">
          <input type="hidden" name="search_form" id="search_form">

          <div class="row">
            <h4 class="text-center">Search for a customer</h4>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="first_name">First Name
                <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Joe" value="<?php echo $search_first_name; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="last_name">Last Name
                <input name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Bloggs" value="<?php echo $search_last_name; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="postcode">Postcode
                <input name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Ex: E2 8AA" value="<?php echo $search_postcode; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <label id="reg">Registration:
                <input name="reg" type="text" placeholder="CV58 CVZ" value="<?php echo $search_reg; ?>">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="button expanded">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

class.search.php

```
<?php

include('config.php');

/**
 * Performs a search
 *
 * This class is used to perform search functions in a MySQL database
 *
 * @version 1.0
 * @author James Brandon
 */
class search {
  /**
   * MySQLi connection
   * @access private
   * @var object
   */
  private $mysqli;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * This sets up the class
   */
  public function __construct() {
    // Connect to our database and store in $mysqli property
    $this->connect();
  }
  /**
   * Database connection
   * 
   * This connects to our database
   */
  private function connect() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
  }

  /**
   * Search routine
   * 
   * Performs a search
   * 
   * @param string $search_term The search term
   * 
   * @return array/boolen $search_results Array of search results or false
   */
  public function search($first_name, $last_name, $postcode, $reg) {
    // Sanitize the search term to prevent injection attacks
    $first_name = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($first_name);
    $last_name = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($last_name);
    $postcode = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($postcode);
    $reg = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($reg);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->mysqli->query("
      SELECT id
      FROM customers
      WHERE first_name = '%{$first_name}%'
      AND last_name = '%{$last_name}%'
      AND postcode = '%{$postcode}%'
      AND reg = '%{$reg}%'
    ");

    // Check results
    if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {
      return false;
    }

    // Loop and fetch objects
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Build our return result
    $search_results = array(
      'count' => $query->num_rows,
      'results' => $rows,
    );

    return $search_results;
  }
}
```

DB:

```
Table: customers
Structure: id | first_name | last_name | postcode | reg
```

So I need to match all that is entered into the form with the database but think I've got as far as I can with changing the code from that tutorial.

Comment: You're mixing your syntax; it's either `WHERE field='something'` for an exact match, or `WHERE field LIKE '%something%'` to use a wildcard. Also, you should look at using a prepared statement instead of just concatenating input into your SQL.

Comment: I think i kind of understand but not 100% ive heard of prepared statements when reading up tonight but im literally new to PHP / MySQL as of this evening haha

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
  $query = $this->mysqli->query("
     SELECT id
     FROM customers
     WHERE first_name LIKE '%{$first_name}%'
     or last_name LIKE '%{$last_name}%'
     or postcode LIKE '%{$postcode}%'
     or reg LIME '%{$reg}%'
 ");
```

Comment: Ill give it a go, im just having a error with an error connecting to database for some reason and details are correct so not sure why so trying to work out but then ill test...

Comment: ok sorted that but getting: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/reboot/public_html/demo/ncddb/class.search.php on line 67

Comment: 67 is: if ( ! $query->num_rows ) {

Comment: I noticed in sql above it has or, or, or i can only return result if all first_nme, last_name, postcode and reg all match

Comment: You can choose to use 'or' or 'and'. It all depends on how want to filter your records from the database. The and is more stricter than the or

Comment: Ok, should i change or to and so i make sure all field match before returning result? and any ideas on that 67 line error?

Comment: Sure if thats what you want to do.

Comment: yep, i submit form but dont seem to get anything back on the search results etc... is it wrong?